# How to fixed responsive background image top & bottom in css?

Tags: css

`background-position: top center`

I want to create a landing page and I have a background image with different design. How to fixed background for all resolutions and all devices?

Comment: Could you please upload the code you already have?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: I just want to see Can a background be fixed up and down?

Comment: @SLH do you have an example of what you would like to achieve visually?

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa  http://uplod.ir/rgrb8tfuyqep/paper-backgrounds.jpg.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can work with media queries to alter your design based on your screen witdh.

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...} 

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...} 

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...} 

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...} 

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

This is an example, but ofcourse add as many media queries as you want.

A second solution is to use "background-size:cover" which will always fill entire background with that picture.

I hope this helps!